# Is there a way to reference theorems which are inside intertext commands?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, amsthm

I am trying to reference a `theorem` that is inside an `intertext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\intertext{\begin{theorem} \label{thm:my-theorem}
My theorem inside intertext.
\end{theorem}}
\end{align*}    
\ref{thm:my-theorem}
\end{document}
```

However, I get:

> Reference `thm:my-theorem' on page 1 undefined on input line 10.

Is there a way to reference theorems inside `intertext`commands?

---

(Of course, my actual use case is less pointless then the MWE. There, I have an `assumption` environment and in the middle of a long calculation I need to introduce an assumption. This is why I nest the `assumption` in `intertext`. However, I think the `theorem` version is more general.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `align`, the `\label` command gets redefined, but you can use the original inside `\intertext`. Assuming that you ***really*** want to do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\intertext{\begin{theorem} \csname ltx@label\endcsname{thm:my-theorem}
My theorem inside intertext.
\end{theorem}}
\end{align*}    
\ref{thm:my-theorem}
\end{document}
```

In order to improve a bit the awful effect, you could use `\shortintertext`, from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a&=b\\
\shortintertext{\begin{theorem} \csname ltx@label\endcsname{thm:my-theorem}
My theorem inside intertext.
\end{theorem}}
c&=ddddddddddd
\end{align*}    
\ref{thm:my-theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Added note

As remarked in comments, this won't work when `cleveref` is loaded. For this case, use `\csname cref@label\endcsname` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I *really really* want - why do you think I shouldn't?

Comment: Looks like my MWE was a bit *too* minimal: In my actual document I also load `cleveref`. Unfortunately this defeats your solution: The label gets printed in the document. However, I naively tried `\csname cref@label\endcsname{thm:my-theorem}` and (to my surprise) it works. Would you mind adding this to your answer (maybe with a short explanation *why* it works – I guess it's kind of a namespace thing)?

Comment: @CL. Also `cleveref` redefines `\label` and, happily enough, it defines its own version as `\cref@label`, to be used in something like `\let\label\cref@label`. So the same trick works, provided one uses `\csname cref@label\endcsname`.